# Windows Service is running but not updating blob/local file

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, service

I have a windows service which uploads some files to blob. I set blob name as year_month_date inside the service. I also log the status in the local folder for cross check. Local log file is created with the same format. Also I set a timer in my service which logs "ping {DateTime.Now.ToString()}". All is working when I install the service. The problem is,service has the status running, but it did not create a new blob with new date in the next day morning. Can anyone help ?
Code :

```
  var blobref = Container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{CityName}/{DateTime.Now.Year}_{ DateTime.Now.ToString("MM")}_{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd")}/{model.CallerId}_{model.InteractionId}{Path.GetExtension(callerMasterModel.FileName)}");
```

But when I restart the service, it again starts working.

Comment: Note that you can replace `ToString()` with format specifier. `{ DateTime.Now.ToString("MM")}` can be written as `{ DateTime.Now:MM}`.

Comment: Ah...ok thanks. But do you have any idea about the actual issue ?

Comment: Nope. I would answer this question if I had any :)